# Using a method as data inside the app parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

So I'm still learning `Vue.js` and I got my list working well and I have one question. I will explain what I'm trying to do below as best as possible and I wanted to see if someone could help me with my issue.

---

So here is the component that I have on the `HTML` side:

```
<favorites-edit-component
    v-for="(favorite, index) in favorites"
    v-bind:index="index"
    v-bind:name="favorite.name"
    v-bind:key="favorite.id"
    v-on:remove="favorites.splice(index, 1)"
></favorites-edit-component>
```

---

Here is the `vue.js` portion that I have:

```
Vue.component('favorites-edit-component', {
   template: `
   <div class="column is-half">
      <button class="button is-fullwidth is-danger is-outlined mb-0">
        <span>{{ name }}</span>
        <span class="icon is-small favorite-delete" v-on:click="$emit('remove')">
          <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
   `,
    props: ['name'],
});

new Vue({
    el: '#favorites-modal-edit',
    data: {
        new_favorite_input: '',
        favorites: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Horse',
                url: 'www.example.com',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Sheep',
                url: 'www.example2.com',
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Octopus',
                url: 'www.example2.com',
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Deer',
                url: 'www.example2.com',
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Hamster',
                url: 'www.example2.com',
            },
        ],
        next_favorite_id: 6,
    },
    methods: {
        add_new_favorite: function() {
            this.favorites.push({
                id: this.next_favorite_id++,
                name: this.new_favorite_input
            })
            this.new_favorite_input = ''
        },
        get_favorite_menu_items: function() {
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
                })
                const Menus = new menus();
                Menus.fetch().then(posts => {
                    console.log(posts.items);
                    return posts.items;
                });
            })
        }
    }
});
```

So as you can see, I have the `data: { favorites: [{}] }` called inside the vue app and I get this console.log:
[image]

Now I built a method called `get_favorite_menu_item` and this is the `return posts.items` output inside console.log:
[image]

---

Problem: I don't want to have a manual array of items, I want to be able to pull in the method output and structure that - How would I take a approach on pulling the items?

Could I call something like this:

`favorites: this.get_favorite_menu_items`?

Here is a JFiddle with all the items: https://jsfiddle.net/5opygkxw/

All help will be appreciated on how to pull in the data.

Comment: do you want to load data from get_favorite_menu_items() to favorites ?

Comment: @Sok yes, I want to load data from the method to favorites instead of defining it manually. I know that I have `id:` in my manual one, but looks like the method returns `ID:` - Would I need to update props or?

Comment: in Vue. we can update data inside method. so we can init favorites to empty array. then on get_favorite_menu_items() after we success get data we can assign it too favorites.

Comment: then on created() Hooks. you can call get_favorite_menu_items() to load data

Comment: @SokHai would you be able to post an example so I can upvote an answer? I think I understand, but it still sounds a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will init favorites to empty array.
then on get_favorite_menu_items() after I will init data from post.item to favorites.
on created() hooks i will call get_favorite_menu_items() to fetch the data when the view is created.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#favorites-modal-edit',
    data: {
        new_favorite_input: '',
        favorites: [],
        next_favorite_id: 6,
    },
    methods: {
        add_new_favorite: function() {
            this.favorites.push({
                id: this.next_favorite_id++,
                name: this.new_favorite_input
            })
            this.new_favorite_input = ''
        },
        get_favorite_menu_items: function() {
            wp.api.loadPromise.done(function () {
                const menus = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
                    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'menus/v1/locations/favorites_launcher',
                })
                const Menus = new menus();
                Menus.fetch().then(posts => {
                    console.log(posts.items);
                    // need map key also
                    this.favorites = posts.items;
                });
            })
        }
    },
    created () {
       // fetch the data when the view is created
       this.get_favorite_menu_items();
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Sok, this is much appreciated! I'm not getting a return but looking into the issue now, but this gives me a good example. I guess the structure would be different on id -> ID or name -> post_title, etc. Also, does it matter that the manual favorites was an object prototype, but the method returns a array prototype?

Comment: @DevSem you need to map you posts.items before assign to favorites.

Comment: Would that involve array.map? possibly loop through and assign the variables?

Comment: @DevSem yes it would involve array.map.

Comment: Hey @Sok, I got a quick question that I might be missing - When I'm console.log() the above code without making any changes, I'm getting a undefined response in `created()` for the `this.get_favorite_menu_items();` method - Would I have to look at something specific?

Comment: @DevSem you might need to check on your network tab. did it fetch correct url or have any response or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228241/discussion-between-devsem-and-sok-hai).